# creating square border around links

Tags: css, hyperlink, hover, border

I'd like to create a border around links that forms a square around the entire link on `:hover`. How do I achieve this effect?

[image: link-border]

Comment: The same way you'd draw a border around any other element. `a:hover { border: 1px solid red; }`

Comment: You are also supposed to show your own attempt at the code.

Answer (score 14):

HTML

```
<a href="#">one</a><br/>
<a href="#">two</a><br/>
<a href="#">three</a><br/>
<a href="#">four</a><br/>
```

CSS

```
a:hover{
 border:1px solid red;  
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wBLdj/)

Comment: The answer is great but, that Fiddle will disappear soon, and StackOverflow questions are forever... Perhaps you could incorporate the code into your answer too (for future reference)? :)

Comment: @TarynEast October 8th, 2020. Fiddle still here

Comment: The point being...  it's unofficial S/O policy not to rely upon code still existing on external sites. It could disappear at any time and it's also annoying to send somebody to another site when they find the answer here. So it's preferred that an answer contain the actual relevant code.